# Netlogo Error: Nothing named NAME? has been defined

Tags: model, netlogo, global

It's my first time here so if I'm not using this correctly please let me know. 
I just started using Netlogo and I'm kind of confused about something. 
In the models library there is the example code for Wolf Sheep Predation. In this code the following is defined:

```
globals [grass]
```

So everything works perfectly fine. But then I started making my own code, using this one as a base and I came across the following error:

> Nothing named Oxygen? has been defined.

In which Oxygen was my own variable. To figure out what was wrong I went back to the Wolf Sheep Predation model and tried to change the name of the global to something else. For example: Strange, (using find and replace all, also with the hand a few times). The result was the same error while if I only changed grass to Grass it would work. Now I would to know are there any specific rules concerning Globals and how they are used and does anyone maybe know why this error is still given within the Wolf Sheep Predation model?

(I would share my own model but it's gotten very long, so it might not be as useful an example).

Comment: All global variables must be declared with `globals`.

Comment: Uhm yes, but what does that mean? Why is it that when you change only the name of a global variables (and of course everything designated to the same name) does the program no longer work?

Comment: If you replace everywhere only the names of the variables declared in `globals`, everything will work fine.  But you declared `Oxygen` while introducing a variable named `Oxygen?`.

Comment: if you share a reproducible example of code it would help us troubleshoot your problem a bit. Feel free to hijack the model I use to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730974/calculating-variance-of-a-turtle-owned-factor-on-a-single-patch-in-netlogo

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with find-and-replace. In the "Wolf Sheep Predation" model there are two global variables with very similiar names. First there is the `grass` variable, that is defined in the `globals [grass]` section. Second, there is a switch-variable on the interface named `grass?`.

If you perform find-and-replace and replace all "grass" strings in the code with "mystring", `grass` will change to `mystring`, but `grass?` will also change to `mystring?`. Because `grass?` is defined on the interface of the model the name of this global will stay unchanged and the code will produce an error as you refer to `mystring?` in the code, but this global is neither defined on the interface nor in the global variable declaration.